# How to Test the code with public void method but private members?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How can you write unit tests for the following Code?

```cs
public class Sample {
   private int a;

   public void SetA(int a) {
     this.a = a;
   }

   public void PrintA() {
    Console.Writeline(this.a)
  }

}
```

Comment: For a true unit test you'd need to find a way to observe the console from code.  That's because this code has a dependency on the console.  Ideally `PrintA` would accept some kind of "printer" object as an injected dependency and print the output to that object.  Then your unit test could inject a mock "printer" and use that mock to observe the behavior.  Basically, what you have here is difficult to unit test because it wraps a dependency.  Invert that dependency and it becomes more easily testable.

Comment: Is there a way for me to check the output from console? In any of the Testing Frameworks lIke XUnit or NUnit or MSTest

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, else I'd be writing that as an answer.  I think the better approach here though would be to modify the code to be more unit-testable.

Comment: Okay lets suppose there is no Console just Public method and private members. How am I suppose to test it?

Comment: In that case you'd test it by invoking the method(s) being tested and observing the result(s).  The general structure of a unit test is "arrange, act, assert".  In this case "arrange" would be creating an instance of your object and a test value, "act" would be calling `SetA` and `PrintA`, and "assert" would be observing the same test value in the result.

Comment: Can you try using Console.SetOut() to a string writer and check the contents of this at the end fo your test method?

Comment: @OguzOzgul that would add dependency of external and then it wouldn't be called unit testing and yes I know Console is a depedency too

Comment: What I do is, despite looking super unnecessary, instantiate my object, call SetA() to a test value and then assert GetA() equals to the same value to check if the assignment was as expected.

Comment: @supernerd: How would that add a dependency?  Currently the dependency on the Console already exists.  Oguz's suggestion would be to inject a mock into *that* dependency.

Comment: But your method has an external dependency. Then you should either mock (which seems not possible for the Console methods, at least I don't know if it is possible), or as @David suggests, get your dependencies from outside using an interface like IConsole